# ajax can't receive blob from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, ajax, file

I want to display pdf in HTML. I receive pdf blob data by ajax from the server. Sometimes it works well. But if pdf data become larger, I could not receive success response. So it seems that somewhere has a limit I can't receive data. How can I do to receive the pdf data?

```
...
  return Git.readVersion(dir, version, grammer);
}).then((blob) => {
  console.info('ddddddddd: '+blob.length);
  return res.status(200).send({ blob: blob, grammer: grammer });
...
```

console show debug info is:

```
ddddddddd: 2550196
POST /api/version 200 61.121 ms
```

in html, my code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/version',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { paperid: pid, version: sha },
  statusCode: {
    200: function (json) {
         if (json.grammer === 'tex') {
           var pdf = base64ToUint8Array(json.blob);
           loadPDF('paper', pdf);
         }
    ...
```

Comment: Are you having any error shown? Could we see them? Could we see your code?

Comment: I guess you shouldTry using to convert blob to file object using --- new File([blob], 'sample.pdf') ---, Although if you could share code?

Comment: @Salketer I add my code above.

Comment: Yeh, but it's missing all the good parts... What's pdf and loadPDF? If you put a console.log in you 200 function, does it always log?

Comment: If I set blob to null, 200 function will always work. If pdf is not so large, it also works. Missing parts maybe add.